# Trouble with cgconfig.conf and cgconfigparser

Tags: cgroup

I get the following error message when I try to run cgconfigparser.

```
:syntax error number 1 at
Error: failed to parse file /etc/cgconfig.conf
cgconfigparser; error loading /etc/cgconfig.conf: Have multiple paths for the same namespace
```

This is my cgconfig.conf file:

```
group coind {
    perm {
            admin {
                    uid = coin;
                    gid = coin;
            }
            task {
                    uid = coin;
                    gid = coin;
            }
    }
    cpu {
            cpu.shares="512";
    }
    memory {
            memory.swappiness="60";
            memory.limit_in_bytes="1073741824";
            memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes="3221225472";
    }
    net_cls {
            net_cls.classid="0";
    }
    blkio {
            blkio.throttle.write_bps_device="";
            blkio.throttle.read_bps_device="";
    }
}
```

I would really like to not have to set this up manually every time i reboot.

Comment: Figured it out, cgconfig.conf was in dos format. Converted it and all is good.

Comment: Glad you figured it out on your own. Please feel free to answer your own question so people see a) this is solved already and b) someone with the same problem might find this helpful. Thanks!